# How to have a Flink job produce to a variable number of Kafka topics without redeployment?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use-case where I need to have a Flink application produce to a variable number of Kafka topics, potentially in different clusters, without having to redeploy the app. Let us assume I maintain the set of destination clusters/topics in config files, and have code in my Flink app that detects and loads any changes in these config files at runtime.

Should I write a custom `SinkFunction` that maintains a set of Kafka producers? Or a custom `SinkFunction` that delegates the work to a collection of `FlinkKafkaProducer` instances? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is deprecated, but you can create your [FlinkKafkaProducer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer.html) using your own serialization schema ( implements [KeyedSerializationSchema](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/util/serialization/KeyedSerializationSchema.html) ) and override the getTargetTopic method.